# How to get all the data from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1.Products

```
prod_id   prod_name
   1       honda
   2       hero
   3       marcedes
   4       audi
```

2.Product to category

```
cat_id  prod_id
  1         1
  1         2
  2         3
  2         4
```

Now i want result like below

```
prod_id    prod_name    cat_id
   1         honda        1
   2         hero         1
   3         marcedes     2
   4         audi         2
```

I cannot seem to figure this out. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good to start with Table Joins form here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select products.*, category.cat_id 
from products, category 
where products.prod_id = category.prod_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select products.prod_id ,products.prod_name, category.cat_id 
from products, category 
where category.prod_id  = products.prod_id
```

Comment: such a little kid with such a high reputation. way to go! L0L!

Answer (score 2):

```
select p.prod_id,p.prod_name,c.cat_id 
from Products p inner join category c 
on p.prod_id = c.prod_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a join, if you only want products has a cat_id, then change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.prod_id, t1.prod_name, t2.cat_id
FORM Products t1
LEFT JOIN ProductToCategory t2 ON t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select p.prod_id, p.prod_name,c.catid
from products p
inner join prodtocat pc on p.prod_id = pc.prod_id